# Why does the `offset` of `ConstantSourceNode` not reflect updated values?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'd like to be able to use a single Audio Param to control the inputs to several other nodes.  For example, this parameter might be a frequency, and I'd like to send that to the frequency of one oscillator, and also send it to a 2x gain and send that to the frequency of another oscillator.

However, when I modify the value of `offset`, I don't see any change reflected in the parameter's value.

Here's a simple example which you can see live here: https://jsfiddle.net/j70fm4pr/2/

```
function log(message) {
  const d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerText = message;
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}

const b = document.createElement('button');
b.textContent = 'Test';
b.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  log('Started.');
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  const cNode = new ConstantSourceNode(ctx, {offset: 0.5});
  cNode.offset.setValueAtTime(1.0, ctx.currentTime);
  log(`Value: ${cNode.offset.value}`);
  setTimeout(() => {log(`Value: ${cNode.offset.value}`);}, 1000);
});
document.body.appendChild(b);
```

Actual Output:

```
Initial value: 0.5
Later value: 0.5
```

Expected Output:
Actual Output:

```
Initial value: 0.5
Later value: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The WebAudio API implementation (at least in Chrome on Linux) won't update any scheduled values unless they have been started and they are connected to a destination.

```
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  const cNode = new ConstantSourceNode(ctx, {offset: 0.5});
  cNode.offset.setValueAtTime(1.0, ctx.currentTime);
  // Start the constant source node.
  cNode.start();
  
  // Create a GainNode so that we can connect the constant source node
  // without having any impact on the final output.
  const g = new GainNode(ctx, {gain: 0.0});
  cNode.connect(g);
  // Actually connect the gain node to the destination.  Without this,
  // the scheduled change has no effect.
  g.connect(ctx.destination);

  // Alternatively, you could use an Analyzer node as the target.
  
  log(`Initial value: ${cNode.offset.value}`);
  setTimeout(() => {log(`Later value: ${cNode.offset.value}`);}, 1000);
```

Note: You can also connect the ConstantSourceNode to the *parameter* of a node which is connected to an output:

```
  const g = new GainNode(ctx, {gain: 0.0});
  cNode.connect(g.gain);
  g.connect(ctx.destination);
```

Output:

```
Initial value: 0.5
Later value: 1
```

I've updated the Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/h1xk5d04/ and connected to a parameter here: https://jsfiddle.net/h1xk5d04/1/